# CGridview custom field sortable

Tags: yii, cgridview

I had created with custom field in yii Cgridview but how to make that sortable. The custom field value is from a function in the model. I want to make this field sortable?
Can someone help me?

Comment: We need a bit more info - did you define a custom sort? What data provider are you using?

Answer (score 4):

In the `search` function of your model, where `customField` is the name of your field:

```
// ...other criteria...
$criteria->compare('customField',$this->customField);

$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
    'customField'=>array(
        'asc'=>'customField ASC',
        'desc'=>'customField DESC',
    ),
    '*', // this adds all of the other columns as sortable
);

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>$sort,
));
```

You may also need to update `rules` and `attributeLabels` in your model to reflect the new custom field.

Comment: can you describe what kind of updates are required for **rules** and **attributeLabels** in model to reflect new custom field. more details please

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed description about searching on custom fields at this URL:

[Using standard filters in CGridView custom fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/117/using-standard-filters-in-cgridview-custom-fields/)