# Yii Sortable Column in CGridView

Tags: sorting, yii, cgridview, cactivedataprovider

I have a calculated column I wanna have sortable.
I have a get method for it...

```
public function getCur_margin() {
        return number_format(($this->store_cost / $this->store_price) / $this->store_cost * 100, 2) . '%';
    }
```

And I followed this thread...

[CGridview custom field sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633516/cgridview-custom-field-sortable)

But now it's looking for an actual column in the database. How can I fetch a field using `<calculations> AS cur_margin` only temporarily for this CActiveDataProvider?

Here is the controller code for the provider:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Products', array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'condition' => 'store_id IN (SELECT `id` FROM `stores` WHERE `user_id` = ' . Yii::app()->user->id . ')',
    ),
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 15,
    ),
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'cur_margin' => array(
                'asc' => 'cur_margin ASC',
                'desc' => 'cur_margin DESC',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to specify your custom field in [select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail) property of `CDbCriteria`?

```
'select' => array(
    ...,   // fields to select
    '(<calculations>) AS cur_margin'
)
```

You don't have to declare getCur_margin() method then but only declare a public `$cur_margin` member in your model. All required calculations will be done in SQL query.

You can also refer to [this thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/13876-cgridview-computed-column-sort/) as an example.

Comment: The column shows, but it has no value and it's still not sortable ):

Comment: Turns out I was adding the select in the wrong place. So let's recap: criteria, compare, and column in gridvieww; this worked, thank you very much!

Comment: where do yo put the select?